# Path Issue while configuring nginx

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nginx

I have a node application running on ports 1111.I have configured server block as

```
server {
            listen 80;
            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            }
            location /app {
            rewrite ^/app(.*) /$1 break;
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1111;
            }
    }
```

index.html file for app is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Node app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>App</h1>
    <div id="nodeApp"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And script.js is

```
var heading = document.getElementById('nodeApp');
heading.innerHTML = "This is node App  contents";
```

The issue is when I run http://127.0.0.1:1111 it works perfectly fine.But what I intend to do is http://127.0.0.1/app and it gets redirected to http://127.0.0.1:1111 but it can not get script.js.I have also tried [Replace image and javascript absolute paths through proxy_redirect in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292479/replace-image-and-javascript-absolute-paths-through-proxy-redirect-in-nginx).
But it did not work.

Comment: Not sure but just an idea, try to give script source full path rather than just script.js provide full http path

Comment: That is not the solution I am expecting.Client side path should be independent of server side configuration.

Comment: You rewrite `^/app(.*)` to `/$1` which adds an extra leading `/`. Try using `$1`.